# state: pending & public-address: null :: Juju setup on local machine

Tags: juju

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Juju stuck in “pending” state when using LXC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134977/juju-stuck-in-pending-state-when-using-lxc)

I've setup Juju on a local VM inside VMWare running on Mac OSX.

Everything seems to be working fine, except when I deployed MySQL & WordPress from the examples, I get the following when I run `juju status`:

```
danny@ubuntu:~$ juju status
machines:
  0:
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: local
    instance-state: running
    state: down
services:
  mysql:
    charm: local:oneiric/mysql-11
    relations:
      db: wordpress
    units:
      mysql/0:
        machine: 0
        public-address: 192.168.122.107
        relations:
          db:
            state: up
        state: started
  wordpress:
    charm: local:oneiric/wordpress-31
    exposed: true
    relations:
      db: mysql
    units:
      wordpress/0:
        machine: 0
        open-ports: []
        public-address: null
        relations: {}
        state: pending
```

`state: pending` and `public-address: null`

Can't find any documentation relating to this issue.
Any help very much appreciated - wonderful idea for a project!