# SSH bootstrap nodes

Tags: juju, maas

After a successful juju bootstrap, still to figure out how to ssh the nodes.
The reason for this is because the juju status command shows that agent-state is not started in two nodes also with instance-state: unknown!!!
It seems that integration of the juju zookeeper  can't be established.

Disabling the firewall is also another alternative as was proposed in askubuntu

[Juju stuck in "pending" state when using LXC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134977/juju-stuck-in-pending-state-when-using-lxc)

looking for a way to SSH to the bootstrap node and dig around in /var/log/zookeeper to figure out the missing part.
Basically, an alternative to do so is to play with file:

/var/lib/cobbler/kickstart/maas.preseed

and change line :

> d-i     passwd/user-password-crypted password !

with :

> d-i     passwd/user-password-crypted    password encrypted_password

Then, bootstrap the machine and login with ubuntu/password [set in the conf file]

The question is that the last file does not exist in maas and juju installation. I saw cobbler in my setting files [ boot server. for more information about it [Cobbler setting](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/08/10/cobbler-how-to-set-up-a-network-boot-server-in-10-minutes/) .
What s the role of cobbler with maas/juju and is it required to ruin zookeeper?

If not, how to ssh the nodes without playing with last trick showed above ?

Thanks for any information shared :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it s possible to ssh the node once your environement bootstraped. Juju already managed for you. Simply, after listing your env by :

> juju status

try :

> juju ssh id_machine

I think it s better way to do it without modifying Cobbler files setting within maas.
But does any one have idea how Cobbler works with maas and why some machines shown in juju status are being in unknown status? agent-status notstarted?

Thanks for any share !!1